# Website links keeps on redirecting to temporary address

Tags: wordpress, webserver

I created a blog at a temporary address provided by my web host.
After buying a domain, I pointed it to the nameserver but the domain always redirects to the temporary address on clicking links.

Support asked me to configure wordpress to my domain name.
I am clueless how to do this. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your wordpress dashboard -> settings -> general and make sure that your WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) are correct!

Comment: That was so simpler than I thought it to be. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome, the smallest things are always overlooked :)